# Unwanted empty table created in datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I am trying to use multiple datasources in my Spring Boot Application, every `entityManager` is creating unwanted tables from other datasources. How can I fix this?
Here's related snippet of my code:

**dataSourceConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef= "entityManagerFactory",
basePackages= {"com.wnp.customerinfo.customerinfo.customerrepository"},transactionManagerRef="transactionManager")
public class CustomerConfig {
    @Bean(name="datasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.customer.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("datasource") DataSource dataSource) {
        Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).properties(properties)
                .packages("com.ecom.customerinfo.customerinfo.model").persistenceUnit("CustomerInfo").build();
    }
    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.customer.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer_info_db_temp
spring.customer.datasource.username=root
spring.customer.datasource.password=
spring.prod.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/prod_info_db_temp
spring.prod.datasource.username=root
spring.prod.datasource.password=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration you used in the class is perfect. But if you have all the model classes in the same package and giving the same base-package in all the configuration classes it will always create the empty tables in all the databases. Try to keep them in different packages.

Comment: Thanks, tried different base packages for different model classes. Worked. :)